# Flink 1.13 UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming

I upgraded the Flink from 1.11 to 1.13 but I got an Exception.

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

This exception is for `out.collect(avroRecord)`

```
@Override
public void flatMap(ObjectNode record, Collector<GenericRecord> out) throws Exception {
    GenericRecord avroRecord = ...;
    out.collect(avroRecord);

}
```

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace. At which points are you using Kryo?

Comment: @ArvidHeise added code